# Mock lodash .isEqual Nodejs Jest Framework Super Test

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocking, lodash, supertest

I am bit stuck testing lodash library lodash library using jest and super test

A.routes.js

```
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();
const _ = require('lodash');
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      let data = req.body
      if(!_.isEqual(data,{"hello":"hello"}){
               console.log('Not Equal') // This line is not getting covered in Code Coverage
            }
     }.catch(e=>{
      console.log(e);
  })
});

export default router;
```

A.route.test.js

```
import a from 'A.route'
import express from 'express';
import supertest from 'supertest';
let _ = require('lodash');

_.isEqual = jest.fn();

describe('API Calls', () => {
    const app = express();
    let request;

    beforeAll(() => {
        request = supertest(app);
    });

    beforeEach(()=>{
        jest.resetModules(); 
    });

test('Successful call to post /', async () => {
        const body= {
            "Hello": "Not Hello"
        };
        
        _.isEqual.mockResolvedValueOnce(false);
        await request.post('/')
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .set('Authorization', 'authToken')
            .send(body);
        
    });
});
```

Code coverage is not able to cover console.log('Not Equal');I tried with _.isEqual.mockImplementation (()=>return false); also tried with _.isEqual.mockReturnValueOnce(false)

Comment: This is generally a *bad idea*. You should test behaviour, not specific implementation. If the function changes to use, say, the Ramda library or another `isEquals`, then your test would now be wrong. Only mock relevant dependencies, not implementation details.

Comment: But then how to get code coverage up..Every where isEqual is not getting mocked, that line is not covered in coverage

Comment: Don't mock it. Call the function in such a way to go through the `if`. Again, you're testing the behaviour, not the implementation. The contract of the function is that when *some condition* is fulfilled you get one output. If it is not, you get another. The specific of how exactly *some condition* is tested are an implementation detail. If you test the implementation detail you 1. get brittle test code that can very easily break with potentially irrelevant refactoring. 2. risk getting the wrong result from the test.

Comment: Number 2. can be a big problem. If you're testing `fn(age)` and it's using `_.gt(age, 18)` and you just mock `_.gt` you might miss that the function is selecting valid voters and you've excluded all 18 year olds which are legally allowed to vote. Therefore the *correct* test is `fn(17) === false` and `fn(18) === true`, rather than `/*mock _.gt to return false*/ fn(42) === false` and `/*mock _.gt to return true*/ fn(42) === true`. Not only have you failed to correctly test the function but the correction of `_.gt` -> `_.gte` breaks your existing tests.

Comment: ok..Let me try some other approach..

Answer (score 1):

You should test the behaviour of this API. This means you should care about the response rather than the implementation details. You should pass in an input, such as `req.body`, to assert whether the result is in line with your expectations.

Since your code cannot be executed, I will arbitrarily add some code to demonstrate

E.g.

`a.router.js`:

```js
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();
const _ = require('lodash');

router.use(express.json());
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let data = req.body;
    console.log('data: ', data);
    if (!_.isEqual(data, { hello: 'hello' })) {
      res.send('Not Equal');
    } else {
      throw new Error('Equal');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.send(`Error: ${e.message}`);
  }
});

export default router;
```

`a.router.test.js`:

```js
import a from './a.router';
import express from 'express';
import supertest from 'supertest';

describe('API Calls', () => {
  const app = express();
  let request;

  beforeAll(() => {
    app.use(a);
    request = supertest(app);
  });

  test('Successful call to post /', async () => {
    const body = {
      Hello: 'Not Hello',
    };
    const res = await request
      .post('/')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('Authorization', 'authToken')
      .send(body);
    expect(res.text).toEqual('Not Equal');
  });

  test('should handle error', async () => {
    const body = {
      hello: 'hello',
    };
    const res = await request
      .post('/')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .set('Authorization', 'authToken')
      .send(body);
    expect(res.text).toEqual('Error: Equal');
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67536129/a.router.test.js (8.606 s)
  API Calls
    ✓ Successful call to post / (48 ms)
    ✓ should handle error (5 ms)

  console.log
    data:  { Hello: 'Not Hello' }

      at examples/67536129/a.router.js:9:13

  console.log
    data:  { hello: 'hello' }

      at examples/67536129/a.router.js:9:13

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 a.router.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.424 s
```